# .htaccess multiple variable rewriting

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I managed to put together .htaccess like this and it is working fine

```
RewriteRule ^$ /splash [L,R=301]        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.examle.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

This redirects things like *example.com/one* to *http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=one*

**However, I would like to add more functionality for my current project so that multiple variables get parsed. So for example:**

```
example.com/category-one?another_variable=some_data&even_more=more_data, etc...
```

get parsed to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cat=category-one&another_variable=some_data&even_more=more_data
```

**Also, is solution like this seo-friendly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `QSA` flag in last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /splash [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: Seems like it is working for first two variables (cat and second one), but if I add one more, then content of second variable is filled like some_data?even_more=more_data

Comment: QSA flag will with **any number** of query parameters. Provide an example of URL for which it didn't work.

Comment: This URL is not correct: `autobazar-ns.cz/garance-kvality?car=abcd?car2=aaa` **since there are 2 `?` in the URI**

Answer (score 0):

try this RewriteRule ^mydir/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ myfile.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]